# How to use SQS sendMessageBatch() to send more than 10 messages?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I was thinking with that piece of code they are sending all the messages to my SQS queue, but when using more than 10 values on my array, I always get the error telling that exceed the limit is reached.

I can't increase my SQS, so I have to send the messages from 10 to 10.

Anyone have a suggestion from the best approach I need to have from that particular case?

```
module.exports.sendMessageBatch = function sendMessages(queueUrl, messages) {    
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length;) {
    var params = { 
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
        Entries: [] 
    };
    for (var j = 0; j < 10 && i < messages.length; i++ , j++) {
        params.Entries.push({
            Id: uuid.v4(),
            MessageBody: JSON.stringify(messages[i])
        });
    }
    return sqs.sendMessageBatch(params).promise();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The [SendMessageBatch - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessageBatch.html) documentation says you can only send up to 10 messages at one time so you will have to write your own logic. Basically split the array in batch of 10 and then send request in a loop. Something like this:

```js
const splitArray = require("split-array");

async function sendMessages(queueUrl, messages) {
  const spilttedArray = splitArray(messages, 10);
  for (const arr of spilttedArray) {
    var params = {
      QueueUrl: queueUrl,
      Entries: []
    };
    for (const message of arr) {
      params.Entries.push({
        Id: uuid.v4(),
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(message)
      });
    }
    await sqs.sendMessageBatch(params).promise();
  }
}
```

There is a package which supports sending bulk messages sequentially and parallely in case you want to go via that route. [sqs-bulk-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqs-bulk-loader)