# Sending messages in bulk using SQS private endpoint

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-vpc, endpoint

I am using nodejs and I need to send bulk messages using sendMessageBatch function to SQS queue. The lambda that will push messages to SQS is inside VPC so I need to use a private endpoint of the SQS.
Can anyone help with the syntax of how to include the endpoint.
I am able to push using this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047048/7649369
However this is not using private endpoint.

```
const splitArray = require("split-array");

async function sendMessages(queueUrl, messages) {
  const spilttedArray = splitArray(messages, 10);
  for (const arr of spilttedArray) {
    var params = {
      QueueUrl: queueUrl,
      Entries: []
    };
    for (const message of arr) {
      params.Entries.push({
        Id: uuid.v4(),
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(message)
      });
    }
    await sqs.sendMessageBatch(params).promise();
  }
}
```

Comment: It should work automatically if the VPC Endpoint has been configured. What happens when you run the Lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#constructor-property) ? You can pass your endpoint as an argument to a SQS client.

```
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({endpoint: 'https://my-vpc-url.com'}) // credentials also
// everything else
await sqs.sendMessageBatch(params).promise();
```